# Data not changed while inserting data from android to mysql database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, insert

I have a problem in inserting data (latitude and longitude) to mysql. when I first run the app, the lat and long are inserted but when I updated the location (lat and long) and insert the data again, only the longitude changes, and the latitude stays the same value as the previous data inserted. I'm totally confused why it doesnt work. I'd be very glad if anyone could help me with this.

This is my code

```
    package com.android.tyegah;

    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;


     import android.app.Activity;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class TyegahActivity extends Activity {
    private LocationManager locationManager;
private Location latestLocation;
private double lat;
private double longi;
private Button updateButton;
private TextView locUpdate;
public String url = "http://servername/file.php";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    locationManager =(LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,onLocationChange);

    locUpdate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locUpdate);
    updateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.updateButton);
    updateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,onLocationChange);
            if (latestLocation.getLatitude() != lat && latestLocation.getLongitude() != longi ) {
                lat = latestLocation.getLatitude();
                longi = latestLocation.getLongitude();  
                }
            String latitude = Double.toString(lat);
            String longitude = Double.toString(longi);
            url  += "?latitude=" + latitude + "&longitude=" + longitude;
            locUpdate.setText(latitude + "," + longitude);
            getRequest(url);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Location updated : Lat: " + latestLocation.getLatitude() +
                    " Lng: " + latestLocation.getLongitude(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }); 

 }


public void getRequest(String Url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        locUpdate.setText(ex.toString());
    }
}

LocationListener onLocationChange = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        latestLocation = location;
        if (latestLocation.getLatitude() != lat && latestLocation.getLongitude() != longi ) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Location updated : Lat: " + latestLocation.getLatitude() +
                " Lng: " + latestLocation.getLongitude(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, onLocationChange);
}

}
```

This is the php file :

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
mysql_select_db("php"); 
$longitude = $_GET['longitude'];
$latitude = $_GET['latitude'];
    if($latitude && $longitude){
      $string= "insert into table (latitude, longitude)values('".$latitude."','".$longitude."')";
       mysql_query($string);
       }

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Did you try getLastBestLocation() method?

Comment: i haven't. I didn't know that method. but thanks for suggesting. I'll try it out :)

Answer (score 0):

just change two lines and try it

in android
u have written

```
if (latestLocation.getLatitude() != lat && latestLocation.getLongitude() != longi )
```

instead that write

```
if (latestLocation.getLatitude() != lat || latestLocation.getLongitude() != longi )
```

AND in php

u have putten

```
$string= "insert into table (latitude, longitude)values('".$latitude."','".$longitude."')";
```

instead put

```
$string= "insert into table (latitude, longitude) values('".$latitude."','".$longitude."')";
```

try it, i think it'll work

Answer (score 0):

You are updating url on onCreate() method and please check Activity life cycle onCreate() method will call first time when activity is created or activity is re created.
I will suggest you to make a call back mechanism to fetch location data whenever you are creating url for server request.

Comment: can you give me a simple example? and thanks for the answer. i'll check on the activity life cycle.